# Erro de tempo em execução '91' A variável do objeto ou a variável do bloco with não foi definida

Tags: banco-de-dados, microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Não sei mexer muito bem com o excel, tenho que fazer um gráfico utilizando botões e deu esse erro

```
Sub logs_acumulador()
'
' logs_acumulador Macro
'

'
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "db_performance.producao[[#All],[logs_acumulador]]")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Plan1!$A$5:$A$124"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa primeiro adicionar o gráfico para que ele seja reconhecido como um objeto e no objeto você pode configurar o intervalo do qual a informação vem:

Use uma linha semelhante a esta com o gráfico que melhor se adapta aos seus dados. Neste caso, é um gráfico de barras:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
```

Código completo:

```
Sub logs_acumulador()
'
' logs_acumulador Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select 'gráfico de barras
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "db_performance.producao[[#All],[logs_acumulador]]")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Plan1!$A$5:$A$124"
End Sub
```

Comment: Agora está dando um outro problema:

Comment: Agora está dando um outro problema:Sub rolinho_fardo()
'
' rolinho_fardo Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select 'gráfico 1
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _ // ERRO EM TEMPO DE EXECUÇÃO 1004 O MÉTODO 'RANGE' DO OBJETO '_GLOBAL' FALHOU
        "db_performance.producao[[#All],[rolinho_fardo]]") // ERRO NESSA LINHA TAMBÉM :(
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Plan1!$A$5:$A$124"
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 3
   End Sub

Comment: Eu acho que pelas regras do `StackOverflow` você tem que criar outra pergunta porque este é um novo erro. Posso ajudá-lo se você criar a pergunta e detalhar que tipo de erros um está tendo é 1004 e o segundo é? Se a minha resposta funcionou para esta pergunta o erro '91' pode marcá-lo como minha resposta como uma resposta à sua pergunta, estou trabalhando na minha reputação. :)